# The finite sets X, Y, Z have |X| = k ≤ |Y | = m ≤ |Z| = n. For how many different pairs (f,g) where f : X → Y, g : Y → Z, is gf : X → Z an injection?

Tags: combinatorics, functions

The finite sets X, Y, Z have |X| = k ≤ |Y | = m ≤ |Z| = n. For how many different pairs (f,g) where f : X → Y, g : Y → Z, is gf : X → Z an injection?

Correct me if I'm wrong, but the number of injections f:X → Y is m!/(m-k)!.
Does this mean that the number of injections gf:X → Y → Z is n!/(n-m!/(m-k)!)!.
Is this correct or am I just a simpleton?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the composition of injective maps is injective. It remains to show that if one of them is not injective, then the composition isn't either.

Now, let $I_1$ the set of all injective maps from $X$ to $Y$. Then, as you noted, $|I_1| = \frac{m!}{(m-k)!}$. Similarly, if $I_2$ is the set of all injective maps from $Y$ to $Z$, $|I_2| = \frac{n!}{(n-m)!}$.

Then the number of such possible pairs is just the number of (ordered) pairs you can form with those two sets, i.e., $|I_1| \cdot |I_2|$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So if I get you right you say that the number is given by m!/(m-k)! * n!/(n-m)!.
But suppose that k=1, m=2 and n=3. Then I get that the number of pairs is 2!/(2-1)! * 3!/(3-2)! = 12. But should it not be just six injective functions which is given by n!/(n-m!/(m-k)!)! = 3!/(3-2!(2-1)!)! = 6 since the single element from X can map to either one of the two elements in Y and similarly the two elements of Y can map to either one of the three elements of Z, hence 6 injective functions. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I certainly understand why there'd be two injective maps from $X$ to $Y$, but I don't see where you get those 6 maps in the end. Besides, it's not about the injective maps $X \to Z$, which would be, trivially, 3; but the **pairs** $(f, g)$ such that $g \circ f: X \to Z$ is injective.

Comment: Also, please use MathJax to format your questions/comments.

Comment: Ok,thanks for the help Cronos2. I thought about it and got a good night sleep and I think I get it.

Comment: If it was useful you can upvote/accept the answer. Cheers!